# GWT 2.6.1 serialization error with Super Dev Mode in IntelliJ 13

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea

I just upgraded to GWT 2.6.1 from 2.5.1 and can't get Super Dev Mode working in IntelliJ anymore. I understand there was an issue with the serialization policy file not getting deployed. We had incorporated the patch for that into our project while we were still on 2.5.1 and it was working. When we upgraded, we deleted that code but it looks like there's something else wrong.

Here's the beginning of the log

```
May 16, 2014 8:18:57 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
INFO: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Key[type=com.gwtplatform.dispatch.server.guice.DispatchServiceImpl, annotation=[none]]: ERROR: The serialization policy file '/scheduler/D766C158B6993C3FAA63D10E1B5BAB34.gwt.rpc' was not found; did you forget to include it in this deployment?
May 16, 2014 8:18:57 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
INFO: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Key[type=com.gwtplatform.dispatch.server.guice.DispatchServiceImpl, annotation=[none]]: Downloaded serialization policy from http://localhost:9876/policies/D766C158B6993C3FAA63D10E1B5BAB34.gwt.rpc
May 16, 2014 8:18:57 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
SEVERE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'net.bookedin.bam.shared.rpc.CheckSessionResult' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = net.bookedin.bam.shared.rpc.CheckSessionResult@538f4b5f
```

So it seems like it can't find the serialization policy file but when I navigate to `http://localhost:8888/scheduler/D766C158B6993C3FAA63D10E1B5BAB34.gwt.rpc`, the file is there.

I've cleared my IntelliJ cache (several times) and run "mvn clean install" a few times. Cleared the browser cache as well and removed and re-created my dev mode and super dev mode configurations in IntelliJ. It works fine launching the devserver from Maven. And now, having run out of options, here I am.

Comment: Please confirm that `CheckSessionResult` looks like `public class CheckSessionResult implements IsSerializable, Serializable {// no arguments constructor}`

Comment: @Braj Confirmed. It extends Result from gwt-platform.

Comment: I encounter the similar problem - my IntelliJ IDEA 15.0 does not deploy the gwt.rpc files. I've checked the files exist but are not included in the deployment. May I ask what patch you installed to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code was the problem. CheckSessionResult returns a User object and I had just added an EnumSet property to it and I guess it can't be serialized. I assumed it was GWT because I was seeing serialization errors in both this call and in another one but both of them return User objects.